# How to add SSL on a custom domain Meteor app?

Tags: ssl, meteor

meteor.com handles ssl by default by just adding https://

But when using meteor.com with a custom domain using origin.meteor.com CNAME, the https:// then give me this chrome warning:

http://clip2net.com/s/4NDmdR

Comment: I, too, get that warning but not for every site, strangely enough. FYI your image link is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a certified ssl certificate with your domain you will have to host it yourself. Each domain must have there own certificate. It would be very hard for them to get around this. This not unique to meteor but any shared hosting.